# how to pass a dynamic key value from a string in mongo data base

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I try to dynamically access a field in mongo database.

The target field is given by this line:

```
var  contextTarget= Session.get('contextLayout')+"BackgroundColor";
```

Where 
`Session.get('contextLayout')` could be either a string or an _id of a collection(eg. userHomeBackgroundColor or 56xhPYg8w3Qtv9xPLBackgroundColor).

I don't know how to access the value. 
I tried this code:

```
    var  contextTarget= Session.get('contextLayout')+"BackgroundColor";
    var tempStore ={};
    tempStore['target']=contextTarget;
    var newTarget = tempStore.target;
    console.log(newTarget);//return the correct value
    var color = customConfiguration.findOne({'author':auth}).newTarget;
    console.log(color);//return undefined
```

It doesn't work. I suppose that it's because the newTarget variable is a string because if I directly write the expected result in the console, it works.How can I do?

**EDIT.**

like said BraveKenny:

```
 var color = customConfiguration.findOne({'author':auth})[contextTarget];
```

In fact, it was not necessary to pass by the object tempStore. With the square brackets keys are properly sent. I had already try it but with a dot before the square bracket.
@Michael: For the schema, I don't have a schema for this collection, because the key names are dynamically created.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, in the end, you want to get a variable attribute of your `customConfiguration` object, which name is contained in `newTarget`.

Maybe try this instead:

```
var color = customConfiguration.findOne({'author':auth})[newTarget];
```

Basically when you type:

```
someObject.toto = 'someValue';
var someAttribute = 'toto';
console.log(someObject.someAttribute); //undefined
console.log(someObject[someAttribute]); // 'someValue'
```

JavaScript will always assume `someAttribute` is an attribute of `someObject` when it's called with a dot notation. Not a variable set in the scope. If you want the value of an attribute `toto` which is contained in a string variable (in my case, `someAttribute`), you have to pass this variable as an index, like this:

```
console.log(someObject[someAttribute]); // 'someValue'
```

Comment: console.log(someObject[someAttribute]); with square brackets works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could describe the schema of the collection `customConfiguration`. I just guess that it contains a collection of documents with just one property each (e.g. `userHomeBackgroundColor` or `56xhPYg8w3Qtv9xPLBackgroundColor`) and you are interested in the one document with the correct property name to read the property value. So I guess, in JSON notation the collection looks something like this:

```
[
  {"userHomeBackgroundColor": "red"},
  {"56xhPYg8w3Qtv9xPLBackgroundColor": "green"},
  {"someOtherConfigProperty" : "someOtherValue"}
]
```

If this assumption is correct, I would replace your original line

```
var color = customConfiguration.findOne({'author':auth}).newTarget;
```

With something like this:

```
var selector = {};             // Empty selector object for findOne
selector[contextTarget] =      // Add dynamic property and as its value
  {$exists: true};             // an object with an $exists-property
                               // with value true

// now find the (first) configuration document having the dynamic property 
var configDocument = customConfiguration.findOne(selector);

// read the value of the dynamic property of the configuration document
var color = configDocument[contextTarget];
```

But to verify this, I need more background about the schema of the collection `customConfiguration`. You might also want to check the documentation of `$exists` (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists) and `findOne()` (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) in the documentation.

If, however, the collection `customConfiguration` contains one configuration document for each author, change your line to just this:

```
var color = customConfiguration.findOne({'author':auth})[newTarget];
```

This solution has been described in a previous answer.

Comment: var color = customConfiguration.findOne({'author':auth})[contextTarget]; is the right solution for me . I can't create a schema for this collection because the keys are dynamically created(when an author post a new page and choose the colour for instance).